# How to get facebook cookie? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, facebook, post, cookies, authentication

I'm using javascript for the facebook login, and for posting action. 
The problem is, if I login on facebook on the page A, I cannot post on a page B because I lost all the facebook information and I have to re-init and to re-log on facebook for posting on a other...
and I would like have a login page, and after the user could navigate on the website and post from any page.
Is there a way to fix that by using the cookie? or anything else? I looked for getting back but cookie but I still not find out how...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to persist the Facebook authentication token somewhere, such as a database. Then, using the javascript API to check if the user is logged in:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = ->
FB.init(appId: '<%= ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"] %>', cookie: true)

$('#sign_in').click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  FB.login (response) ->
    window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse
```

There are several moving parts to a Facebook web app, including client and server authentication. You should check out this Railscast which very thoroughly describes the process:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

and you can even pull source code: http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/sources/360-facebook-authentication.zip

Comment: but is there a way to get the facebook cookie? that will be easier no?

Comment: yep, check out FB.init in the Javascript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Comment: I checked but they don't tell how can we use the cookie ... that's the problem ....